# What kind of bus?

Tags: riddle

**What kind of bus has a driver, but doesn't drive?**

Hint:

> It can transport things without physically moving.

Hint:

> This is a very common thing and it does exist in reality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could be a:

> USB (Universal Serial Bus).

It can transport things without moving, and is very widely used.

Comment: Wow, quick answer! I was thinking maybe Airbus...

Comment: Just to nitpick at the puzzle (not that it's bad) ...this bus does *not* have a driver, the device it is being used with does (or indeed may have many); the bus itself works without a driver and it transports some things without moving prior to the driver even being known or available (power and interface descriptors at least). Oh and a warm welcome to Puzzling both of you (sorry to sound so lame)!